# Displaying contracted hours and overtime in C

Tags: c, if-statement, numeric

I'm writing a program that asks for the hours worked and the rate of pay then calculates their earnings. If the person were to work more than 40 hours they'd start earning overtime.

How do I get it to display the total earned up to 40 hours excluding overtime? "`salary=hours<=40*rate;`" just comes back as $1. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int hours;
    float rate,salary,totalPay, tax, netPay, overtime;
    printf("Enter # of hours worked: ");
    scanf("%d",&hours);
    

    printf("Enter hourly rate of the worker: ");
    scanf("%f",&rate);


    if (hours>40)
      {
        salary=hours<=40*rate;
         overtime=(hours-40)*rate*1.2;
         printf("Salary is $%.2f\n",salary);
         printf("overtime is $%.2f\n",overtime);
      }
      
    else
     { 
       salary=hours*rate;
       printf("Salary is $%.2f\n",salary);
       printf("No overtime has been earned\n");
     }


    totalPay=salary+overtime;
    printf("The total pay is $%.2f\n",totalPay);


     tax= totalPay*.25;
     printf("The amount of tax deducted is $%.2f\n",tax);

     netPay=totalPay-tax;
     printf("The net pay is $%.2f\n",netPay);
    return 0;

    


}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stack overflow. Could you edit your question to provide a minimum reproducible example? As in, a minimum working code that can be compiled? There is some ambiguity (such as the datatypes of the variables)

Comment: Here's the link: [mcve]

Comment: `salary=hours<=40*rate;` --> `salary=40*rate;`

Comment: That was so simple I didn't even think about it! I tend to overthink things. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't doing what you want:

```
salary=hours<=40*rate;
```

It groups as `salary = (hours <= (40 * rate))`, which is comparing `hours` to `40 * rate`, so it will evaluate to either `0` (false) or `1` (true), depending on the values.  Just change it to this:

```
salary = 40*rate;
```

You already know that `hours >= 40`, so you just want to use `40` here.  The amount above `40` is used on the next line for the overtime.